# Static Linking After the Fact

Tags: linker, language-agnostic, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Would it be possible (whether or not any tools are currently capable of this) to statically link in some or all dynamic library dependencies of an executable after it's been compiled?  I mean modifying the executable, not recompiling it from source.

For instance, if I compile `a.out` and link it against sqlite, `otool -L` (or ldd) will show `/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib`.

The modification I'm talking about is some tool that would take `a.out + libsqlite3.dylib = b.out` without the runtime dependency on `libsqlite3.dylib`.

Since static linking is basically copying the library code into the executable, I can't think of any instance where `libsqlite3.dylib` would be missing some code that `libsqlite3.a` would have.

I could imagine a really ugly proof-of-concept where the dynamic linker would read the relevant code from the executable and masquerade it as a dynamic library.

Of course this wouldn't work with dynamic loading (e.g. dlopen).